# Question regarding the Asymptotes of Hyperbola

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

Take a curve ,some curve which $converges$ to a point as one variable( say $x$)tends to $\infty$

$(ie)$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ ${y\to L}$

,the value that it approaches (or) converges to ( $y$ value)  ,is the value of the asymptote ,the value that the curve tries to reach($y$ reluctantly tries to get to )but never reaches (or) only reaches the value at $\infty$.

Now the equation of Hyperbola is given by

$\frac{x²}{a²}$ - $\frac{y²}{b²}$=1

To find the asymptotes we substitute $\frac{x²}{a²}$-$\frac{y²}{b²}$=0

Why do we do that ?

What is happening here?

**Is there any geometrical reasoning for this?**

*To find the asymptotes we take the RHS of the equation as 0,why so?*

Comment: Divide the equation of the hyperbola by $x^2/a^2$ and take the limit $x\to\infty$. What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the projective equation (in homogeneous coordinates) of your hyperbola is
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=z^2
$$
and the asymptotes correspond with the points "at infinity", that is, $z=0$.